# Mac Mail won't connect to Exchange 2007

Tags: mac, mail.app, email, ms-office

We recently had a mail outage and eventually got mail back - it was a disk space issue. The PCs with Outlook can connect in without issues but the couple of Macs we have won't connect at all. I can ping the server, etc. and have the Mac connector enabled in Exchange also.

I'm totally lost on this one. Users are connecting through the Outlook Web App for the time being, but that's not ideal. When I try using the Connection Doctor it asks about enabling SSL which is already enabled. It won't log the account on; I've tried resetting the password as well.

Comment: Can you give more details? This is pretty vague, and Welcome to StackExchange :)

Comment: not really a mac person, thats the main problem, so unsure what other details I can provide. Everything was working fine until the server fell over.

Comment: Were there any new certificates generated in this process?

Comment: Hi Bispymusic, thanks for your reply, no new certs were generated by the reboot, regards.

Comment: Have you tried deleting that entry from the login keychain? Trashing Mail preferences file? Am assuming Restarts between trial fixes. too. And that you've run Disk Utility and repaired permissions, too.